# How to handle silent push notification in ionic cordova application?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm following ionic documentation to create ionic [push notifications](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch). This works fine when the app is in active state. I need to run a function when the app receive a push notification while the app is in background.

```
$ionicPush.register({
  canShowAlert: false, //Should new pushes show an alert on your screen?
  canSetBadge: true, //Should new pushes be allowed to update app icon badges?
  canPlaySound: false, //Should notifications be allowed to play a sound?
  canRunActionsOnWake: true, // Whether to run auto actions outside the app,
  onNotification: function(notification) {
    // Called for each notification.
  }
});
```

The issue i'm facing is `onNotification` callback function does not firing when the app is in background. How do I achieve that using ionic push notification API?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `onNotification` will be only fired when you click on notification in tray, which open applications. If notification is in android tray, it means notification has not been seen, because of which it will never reach application unless you click on it.

Comment: Yes...But I want to do some functionality when a push notification received to the device. Like in silent push notifications which will wake up the app in background, I want ionic event to be fired when the app is in background when a push come to the device. any help or suggestion on that?

Comment: @Aruna i don't know if that is possible, that is exactly the purpose of notifications that let user only activate application when he want to by clicking on notification by his own consent. But push notifications can't help you with that, this is i am sure about.

Comment: @Aruna please accept the answer if it clear your confusion regarding push notifications. And i will suggest you to post new question regarding your actual requirement.

Comment: I admire your suggestion. I didn't get a solution for my question which is  "How to handle silent push notification in ionic cordova application?". There is a thing called silent push notification which wake up  the app when the device receive a silent push notification. So i'm waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this patch may solve your problem:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/288
(quoted here in case it disappears)

```
    We have managed to get this plugin to respond to silent push notifications which in turn call javascript functions, all while running in background mode. I thought we would share our solution as it seems like a lot of people are wanting this feature.

In AppDelegate+notification.m, change didReceiveRemoteNotification:

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveNotification");

    // Get application state for iOS4.x+ devices, otherwise assume active
    UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
        appState = application.applicationState;
    }

    PushPlugin *pushHandler = [self getCommandInstance:@"PushPlugin"];
    pushHandler.notificationMessage = userInfo;
    if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive)
        pushHandler.isInline = YES;
    else
        pushHandler.isInline = NO;
    [pushHandler notificationReceived];

    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
In Pushplugin.m, change notificationReceived:

- (void)notificationReceived {
    NSLog(@"Notification received");

    if (notificationMessage && self.callback)
    {
        NSMutableString *jsonStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"{"];

        [self parseDictionary:notificationMessage intoJSON:jsonStr];

        if (isInline)
        {
            [jsonStr appendFormat:@"foreground:\"%d\"", 1];
            isInline = NO;
        }
        else
            [jsonStr appendFormat:@"foreground:\"%d\"", 0];

        [jsonStr appendString:@"}"];

        NSLog(@"Msg: %@", jsonStr);

        NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", self.callback, jsonStr];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

        //get javascript function to fire in background mode
        CDVPluginResult *commandResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:jsonStr];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:commandResult callbackId:self.callbackId];

        self.notificationMessage = nil;
    }
}
```

Assuming you are willing to adapt it to work with the
current non-deprecated plugin:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push